# How does Victor Stone gain new abilities?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, justice-league-2017

In the 2017 Justice League movie, Victor is talking to his father about how he has turned into something he doesn’t understand, as seen below in this clip:

The exact quote is found below.

> **Victor:** Every day I wake up different...modified.
>
> *Victor flies into the air with jets on his feet.*
>
> **Victor:** I couldn’t do that last night.

My question is, how exactly is this happening to Victor? I’ve been looking through the movie but haven’t found a detailed explanation on what exactly is causing these changes and why they are occurring.

Comment: Because he got zapped by the box thingie.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Valorum noted in his comment, Victor has the technology of an Apokoliptan [Mother Box](https://dccomicsextendeduniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Mother_Box) integrated into his physiology. It is not explicitly spelled out in the film, but it's implied that the box integrated with the cybernetics Silas had implanted in him to save his life after the car accident, with his system partially being under Victor's control and partly being co-opted by the Mother Box to further its purpose, whatever that is. Thus, one of Victor's prime complaints in the film is that he is becoming more alien and more machine as the Mother Box transforms him, with one of his fears being that the transformation will remove the part of him that is human, and Victor Stone, leaving just the machine.

Comment: That's fascinating. I knew that the Mother Box changed him after his father used it on him, but I didn't expect the Box to continue modifying him for it's own purpose.